How to use Regex with extract in Swift switch expression?
I am building on this stackoverflow question.
I would like to extract some values from the regex match, depending on the case:
extension String {
    func matchFirst(_ regex: Regex<Substring>) -> Bool {
        (try? regex.firstMatch(in: self)) != nil
    }
}

func decodeString(_ leg: String) {
    switch leg {
    case let s where s.matchFirst(/ABC/):
        print("Found ABC")
    case let s where s.matchFirst(/(?<value>\d{2})/): // Does not work
        print("Found \(s.value)")
    default:
        print("<no match>")
    }
}

The second case in the above example does not compile : Error: cannot convert value of type 'Regex<(Substring, value: Substring, Substring)>' to expected argument type 'Regex<Substring>.
I would like the second case to act like this snippet:
let r = /(?<value>\d{2})/
let leg = "In 3 days, I will be 22 years old."

if let s = try? r.firstMatch(in: leg) {
    print("My age is \(s.value)!")
}

/// prints "My age is 22!"

How can this be achieved?

"How can this be achieved" What is "this"? What is that line of code supposed to do?

The second case should be triggered when the regex is matched (in this example, when a 2 digit number is found) and the value of that number should be available in the case method (as s.value in this example) for further treatment of that value.

Probably because your regex is wrong.  If you're trying to capture 2 occurrences of a digit it should be (?<value>\d{2}) with braces not parentheses.  However I don;t think the wife regex parser will handle named captured groups in that way.

I don't understand how the regex in that line would do what you are describing. (In fact I don't understand the regex at all.) Can you show an example of the string you are matching against and what you expect this regex to match in that string?

Sorry, my mistake - regex should be /(?<value>\d{2})/ corrected in question. This regex should match the first 2 digit value found, and make it available through s.value.

How exactly would it "make it available through s.value"?

I have added a snippet in the question that shows how the s.value works outside of a switch ... case.

Even with your corrected regex it won't do what you expect. The switch ... case ... let ... where will see if the input string (leg in your case) represented as s in the switch successfully matches the regex and if so return the s string, not the regex output. This is why your capture group is causing an error - it makes no sense in the context of func matchFirst(_ regex: Regex<Substring>) -> Bool.
You'll need to do a bit more work to extract the actual match:
func decodeString(_ leg: String) {
   
   switch leg {
      case let s where s.matchFirst(/ABC/):
         print("Found ABC")
      case let s where s.matchFirst(/\d{2}/):
         let matches = s.matches(of: /(?<value>\d{2})/)
         print (matches.first!.output.value)
      default:
         print("<no match>")
   }
}

Once you've established there is a match in the switch, use the input string in a regex matches(of:) that will allow you to extract the match results and then access the named capture group.
EDIT re comment...
Yes, there are possible solutions, such as the one below, but they are all inelegant and inflexible:
func extract(from leg: String) -> Substring? {
   guard let match: Regex<Substring>.Match = switch leg {
      case leg where leg.contains(/ABC/): leg.firstMatch(of: /ABC/)
      case leg where leg.contains(/\d{2}/): leg.firstMatch(of: /\d{2}/)
      default: nil
   } else {return nil}
   return match.output
}

I think you're looking in the wrong direction however.  Not knowing the wider context, but I'd probably use an extension on String that took in a collection of regexes, filtered, and returned the matching regex and its output.
And as an example, something like this, which returns an array of Substring as there's a chance of more than one regex matching.
extension String {
   func matching(_ regexes: [Regex<Substring>]) -> [Substring] {
      regexes.compactMap{self.firstMatch(of: $0)?.output}         
   }
}


Thanks for proposing this and I can see how it all works now. Would there be any elegant way to do both regexes (the check and the extraction) in one-go?

An alternative to using switch could be to make the matchFirst take one or more regex patterns as argument and return the first match (or nil)
extension String {
    func matchFirst(_ patterns: Regex<Substring>...) -> String? {
        for pattern in patterns {
            if let match = try? pattern.firstMatch(in: self) {
                return String(self[match.startIndex..<match.endIndex])
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

Or a tad shorter and cleaner code if we use firstRange as suggested by @vadian
    func matchFirst(_ patterns: Regex<Substring>...) -> String? {
        for pattern in patterns {
            if let range = self.firstRange(of: pattern) {
                return String(self[range])
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}


Or if let range = self.firstRange(of: pattern) { return String(self[range])}

Thanks, sometimes there are almost to many options :)

A switch pattern match evaluates to a boolean value, you cannot get any arbitrary return value, not even without the <value> annotation.
My suggestion is to define a Regex pattern matching operator in the String extension
extension String {
    static func ~=(regex: Regex<Substring>, str: String) -> Bool {
        str.contains(regex)
    }
}

This shortens the code considerably but anyway you have to perform another Regex search in the second case
func decodeString(_ leg: String) {
    switch leg {
        case /ABC/:
            print("Found ABC")
        case /\d{2}/:
            let match = leg.firstMatch(of: /(?<value>\d{2})/)!.output.value
            print("Found \(match)")
        default:
            print("<no match>")
    }
}

or simpler without ?<value>
let match = leg.firstMatch(of: /\d{2}/)!.output
print("Found \(match)")

